# Generating User Achievement Visuals for Social Media Sharing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, social-media

I am looking for a way to generate a visual that contains certain information specific to each user such as his/her achievements. My goal is to create such graphic bearing a generic template but having dynamic data added to it inside app before sharing it to social media like facebook, whatsapp and twitter.

Does anyone know how to generate such visuals inside an app? Are there any tools, plugins available that can be integrated with ionic?

Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

After some rigorous search on the internet, I found one company by the name **imgIX** that  offers image url API. It's amazing to find the amount of editing that can be done to images programmatically. Here is the link: https://www.imgix.com/

Although, they do charge for it but also provide a free trial period which I believe is great should one needs to test their api functionality and integration with web/ mobile apps.

Will definitely go for this service, and hope others looking for similar solutions can find this read helpful.